# How to add tooltip in the "start menu entry"

Tags: install4j

I added "start menu" by "Add Action -> "Desktop integration" -> "Create start menu entry"

I want to add tooltip(description) this menu as below

[image]

How to add this in the "start menu"

If not, How can I make "start menu entry" by custom code

Comment: This is currently not supported by install4j.